# how to send data into table using Post method

Tags: sql-server, android-studio, post

```
{
"response":{
                  "firstname":"Fir",
                  "frlogs":[
                     {
                        "action":"test3",
                        "dateverified":"2019-07-04 10:55",
                        "membershipappid":"0000000000",
                        "isverified":"true",
                        "lastverified":"2019-07-04 10:55",
                        "transactiondate":"2019-07-04"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }



public void sendPost() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("my url");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
          conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
          conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
          conn.setDoOutput(true);
          conn.setDoInput(true);
          JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
          JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
          obj.put("action", "Success");
          obj.put("dateverified", currentDateandTime);
          obj.put("membershipappid", AppData.usrID);
          obj.put("isverified", "True");
          obj.put("lastverified", currentDateandTime);
          obj.put("transactiondate", currentDateandTime);
          array.put(obj);
          DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
          os.writeBytes(obj.toString());
          os.flush();
          os.close();
          conn.disconnect();
          } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
          }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: i want to send json data but under the frlogs

Comment: like the sample above